# Using a UWP C++ dll in Win32 C# WPF application

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, interop

I'm attempting to use the SimpleCommunication C++ DLL that Microsoft in one of their UWP sample examples inside a Win32 C# WPF application.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication/common/MediaExtensions/Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication

I've tried to add a reference to the both the .dll and .winmd files that are generated when building the SimpleCommunication .dll into my Win32 C# WPF application however whenever I attempt to call any function from SimpleCommunication I get the following exception message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
>       An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>       Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Microsoft.Samples.SimpleCommunication.StspMediaSinkProxy'.

As far as I know this C++ dll is being built as a C++/CX (because its using the /ZW flag in the compiler) and because of this it contains unmanaged code, so I'm assuming I'll need some sort of wrapper to be able to call these functions from my managed wpf application but I'm not really sure what the best way to approach this would be, any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What's with the image?

Comment: No wrapper is necessary, this works just like COM does.  The .winmd file plays the exact same role as a type library, without the need to generate an interop library for it.  We can't see your test program, makes it hard to help you.  Maybe there's something wrong with the .winmd file, have a look-see at it with a decompiler like ILSpy or ildasm.

Comment: I managed to solve it following the instructions here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/08/02/using-a-windows-runtime-component-from-a-win32-application/

Incase the link is broken here is a screenshot of the page: https://i.imgur.com/6GD606s.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although WPF applications can use **system-provided** WinRT types (those in the `Windows` namespace), they cannot use custom WinRT types because Windows doesn't know how to locate them. The solution is to [use the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) to add your WPF application to an AppX package, at which point Windows will be able to locate and activate your types.

(Note: you *do not* have to submit your app to the Store to use the Desktop Bridge; it's just a mechanism to package your app).

Comment: I've tried doing this and I've ran into some issues when adding a reference to the custom WinRT library. I created a "Windows Application Packaging project" in VS2017 (running windows build 15063) and added both my c# application and the WinRT c++ library as references. When attempting to create an instance of an object that exists within the WinRT c++ CLI in my C# application I get these exceptions:

Exception thrown at 0x7659CBB2 (KernelBase.dll) in myapplication.exe: WinRT originate error - 0xC00D36B2 : 'The request is invalid in the current state.'.

(see next answer)

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x7659CBB2 (KernelBase.dll) in myapplication.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070005 : 'Activation of per-user ActivatableClassId denied from non-AppContainers'.

Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in myapplication.exe

Comment: I think the issue might be my windows 10 build, I found this microsoft repo where it is stated in that "- Calling WinRT Components from Win32 apps requires the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update or higher" https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/WinFormsWinRTComponent

Comment: It's still true that you need to package your app as of the Creators Update.

Comment: I solved all my issues, I ended up following the instructions here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/08/02/using-a-windows-runtime-component-from-a-win32-application/ and managed to get it up and running, thanks for the help!